# Are there any local shops to buy/eat shortbread in Edinburgh?

Tags: uk, food-and-drink, shopping, edinburgh

I had several trips to Edinburgh, but Google Maps and Foursquare didn't help me to find shortbread different from usual<sup>*</sup>. At least I would like to try something never packaged, for example directly served in a bakery.

Is it possible to find a shop or bakery that has something not common?

<sup>* Can be easily found anywhere in the UK, specifically in England</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really know what you consider "unusual" (other than fresh/store-made rather than packaged); I can't think offhand of styles of shortbread that would be available in Edinburgh but not elsewhere in the UK. However, [millionaire's shortbread](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caramel_shortbread) (shortbread layered with caramel and chocolate) is yummy, and [this place](https://www.facebook.com/TheHavenCafe) appears to have it (and still be open, unlike other Google hits). From what I can see they appear to do their own baking. [The recommendation](https://www.tripadvisor.ca/ShowUserReviews-g186525-d2626599-r178145398-The_Haven_Cafe-Edinburgh_Scotland.html) was from 2013, though, so you might want to phone or facebook-message them and check before going out of your way ...

[image]